# Poor 'him' or 'he'? Reason?

Tags: pronouns

I checked many dictionaries and the examples of *poor* in the context of sympathy state 'thing', 'you' or a direct name (proper noun). I wonder what is the correct form of the pronoun there?

> Poor *him/he*?

Ngram shows [both in practice!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poor%20she%2Cpoor%20her&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoor%20she%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoor%20her%3B%2Cc0)

Reason?

Comment: Here is one similar question :  
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s

Comment: @vkumar went through the accepted answer. It makes the question 'firmer' rather than answering it! :P

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question, using objective case is general is OK, so you could say "poor him", but not "poor he". For example: "I heard he failed the test. Poor *him*. Though I wonder if this form is used much, because we probably know who it is and would use a name or generic term (guy, girl etc.) The idiom "poor thing" is a condescending usage; generally you are looking down upon such a person or treating them as inferior.

Comment: It's more common to say *poor you/any name*, but *poor him* is also common. But *poor he* is not so common, I don't know if it's incorrect.

Comment: @Man_From_India *poor he* is **not** incorrect! That's what the question is! :(

Comment: The use of the accusative is standard English. The nominative is non-standard. You should inspect your Ngram data for usage of *"poor she"* and see if there really are any. The linked to thread (in comment by v kumar) actually answers your question, especially the top two answers.

Comment: @F.E. Thanks I just google it, and found, as you said, it's non standard. Everywhere it's objective case. And came to know very few adjectives comes before pronouns. How to identify such adjectives?

Comment: @MaulikV The graph you showed mightn't reflect the real situation. What if the recorded text is like this: **She is poor. She for that reason had to discontinue her studies.** In this case google ngram will pick it as an occurrence of **poor she**, but that is not the case here. I checked BNC for **poor he**, there were hardly 4-5 results. And they all are irrelevant here. **poor** is attached with something else and **he** is attached with something else.

Answer (score 5):

I've always heard this as "Poor him", never "Poor he".

Note this is not a complete sentence, so it's difficult to say what grammar rules apply. There is no verb. I suppose the grammatically correct way to say it would be, "He is poor". Though in this case, that would change the meaning, as "He is poor" would be understood to mean that he is lacking in money, while "Poor him" means that he is a victim of some bad circumstance, possibly involving money but usually not. We typically say things like, "Bob's dog died yesterday. Poor him." Of course losing his dog probably doesn't not hurt him financially, but rather emotionally.

Usually in this sort of construct we use a noun rather than a pronoun. We'll say, "Bob's dog died yesterday. Poor Bob.", rather than "Poor him." But it's not unheard of with the pronoun.

Many other adjectives can be used in the adjective-noun form. "Good dog." "Foolish boy." "Lazy fellow." Etc. I guess any of these could be used with a pronoun, when the person or thing meant by the pronoun is clear from the preceding context.

Answer (score 4):

> - Poor her!
> - Poor she!

The pronoun ***she*** is normally used as the subject of a verb which has tense. The normal pronoun, if there is no full tensed verb, is *her*. It does not matter if the pronoun is the subject of a verb or not. It matters if the verb has tense:

- I remembered her singing Lady Gaga songs.
- I think she liked my elephant.

In the first sentence, we see a clause with --ing. It isn't past tense or present tense. Because the clause has no tense, we don't use *she*. But in the second sentence, *she* is the subject of *liked*. The word *liked* is past tense. We need *she* not *her*.

In the exclamation *poor her*, the word *her* isn't the subject of a proper verb with a tense. It isn't the subject of a verb at all! So this exclamation is good. It uses *her*.

However, the utterance *Poor she* is ungrammatical - in normal, standard English. This is because we need a tensed verb for *she*. In this utterance, there is no verb. So there is no tensed verb either!

If you look at Ngrams, you will think that there are some sentences with *poor she*. But this is not true. Ngrams do not show which exact sentences these words are in. Here is a list of examples from books from Ngrams. It is the actual list of examples of the words  [*poor* and *she*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22poor+her%22&oq=%22poor+her%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3249j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22poor+she%22&start=10) in published books. If you look at the examples you will see that *poor* and *she* are not in the same clauses. Sometimes, they are not in the same sentences. Here are some of the examples:

- They are very **poor. She** never thought that a village woman could be the subject of a photograph.
- She was the physician of the **poor. She** had learned to be useful in sickness
- Hillary is so **poor, she** pays taxes at rates like 35%

In the first two examples, the words *she* and *poor* are in different sentences. In the third example, *poor* is in the clause:

- Hilary is so **poor**

But the word *she* is the subject of a different clause. This clause is:

- **she** pays taxes at rates like 35%

This shows that the words *poor* and *she* don't have a grammatical relationship in the sentence. Usually, we can only use *she* for the subject of a present tense or past tense verb. When there is no verb, or the verb has no tense, we need to use the word *her*!

**The Original Posters's question**

There is no verb in the sentence:

- Poor she/her.

Because we usually only use *she* with tensed verbs, *poor she* is ungrammatical in modern, standard English. Instead we need:

- Poor her!

Hope this is helpful!

[There is another [interesting problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s) which is not part of the Original Poster's question. Some pronouns which *do* seem to be the subject of tensed verbs are still accusative. In other words they take *her* and not *she*. The answers in the linked-to post are very interesting. But this is really a different problem altogether. The situation with our question here follows the normal pattern of the grammar]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Ngram shows both – but did you take a closer look?

[image]

Many of those "poor her" quotes are *false hits*; they are found in passages such as:

> Mother Teresa helped the **poor**. **Her** compassion is well-known and admired.

When used as a two-word expression, I rarely hear a third-person pronoun used. Instead, it's often the name of person:

> Poor Maulik! He's confused about English again. What a vexing language it is.

Then there is this classic line:

> The worms were eating in Ernest. Poor Ernest.

which is a humorous pun using the name *Ernest* and homophonous adjective *earnest*.

Comment: True but then what about the case wherein I *don't know* the name of that poor! Say, someone is telling me -In my office, there's a person. He works too hard but doesn't get appreciation. I, in reply, say - *'Ah, poor him!'* Would you mind putting some light in your example on **why**

Comment: @MaulikV - If I don't know the name, I usually say something like "Ah, that poor guy." I realize my answer wasn't complete but I thought it was important to point out the danger of looking at Ngram totals only.

Answer (score 1):

Pronouns don't normally allow an adjective before it.

Consider the following sentence -

> **You** are **interesting**, and you allowed me to contact you for this academic project.

This is fine, but if we want to place the adjective before the pronoun, it will be incorrect, and hence the following sentence is not correct -

> - **Interesting you** allowed me to contact you for this academic project. (INCORRECT)

But there are few adjectives that are exception to this rule. (**e.g.** poor, silly, lucky etc.). These adjectives are semantically non-restrictive.

After such adjectives the nominal form of pronoun is correct. Using subjective form with those adjective will be incorrect.

When we form a noun phrase combining such adjectives and the objective case of personal pronouns, we can use that noun phrase as a stand alone exclamation (**e.g** - *Poor me!*), the subject (**e.g** - *Lucky him won the first prize.*), and the object (**e.g** - *It was done by poor me.*).

So the main thing here is to identify which adjectives functions like this way. We have already found a few. Now the question is if any other adjectives can be used this way? If yes, how to identify them? These are the main questions that my answer doesn't include, because I myself don't know :( If anyone knows, I request him/her to please share this info.

Thanks.

Comment: "Lucky him won the first prize" > I would change this to "Lucky him! He won the first prize"

Comment: Starts off as a good answer as it follows http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s which is the-answer-on-steriods.

Comment: On the other hand, I think it starts to lose focus at *Not only all adjectives can not be used this way, but not all pronouns can be used this way. Only core personal pronoun can be used this way.* Firstly, that first sentence is confusing.  Next, what's a "core personal pronoun"?  All personal pronouns except *it*?  Is there a point really being made here, or was @DamkerngT.'s quote taken out of context? IMHO, I think the point about "it" (as presented here) seems tangential to the question and distracts from the answer.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Yes, that makes me think. You are right. There is ambiguity. Let me check with my grammar book. "It" is also a personal pronoun.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis I didn't find much. It's interesting that if "it" refers to a poor animal, why can't we say "Poor it"? "It" is also a personal pronoun.

Comment: I can make an "educated conjecture". The word *it* can be used to refer to animals or people (e.g. used in some cases to refer to babies of unknown sex).  However, *it* predominately refers to objects, we don't express empathy towards objects, and so "poor it" is functionally contradictory.  Expressing empathy towards an object is possible, but in that case we always name the object. *"I have a pet rock! Poor rock!  It just sits there all alone, day after day."*

Comment: Quibble: "Interesting you allowed me to contact you" is perfectly valid and a construct English speakers use all the time. It is a short version of "It is interesting that you allowed me to contact you." But of course this isn't the meaning that you had in mind when you wrote the sentence, so I'm not disputing your point.

Comment: I think the real rule is more complex. Yes, "Interesting you allowed me ..." would not be understood to mean that "interesting" is modifying "you". But "Cruel you refused to allow me ..." would, I think, be readily accepted and understood. "Beautiful you accept my proposal of marriage" is awkward but comprehensible.

Comment: @Jay right. I was trying to think of "interesting you", actually in that sentence there is a pause before "you". And as you said "interesting" is not modifying "you", but the fact that you allowed me:)

Answer (score 1):

@CoolHandLouis in the comments provided a link to a [great detailed answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/why-do-we-use-the-object-instead-of-the-subject-pronoun-in-constructions-like-s) to this on english.stackexchange.com.

The reason why this is happening is detailed here:

> So what happens is that you are taking ADJECTIVE PRONOUN, which takes the objective case, and then turning around and using that as a third-person subject, even when it is a first- or a second-person thing. **This distances the speaker a bit from what they are saying, as though it were someone else they were talking about.** It is hard to see how else one would phrase such a thing. Consider: ...

Basically in something like "poor him", "lucky me" or "stupid him" you are, in a sense, talking about "he", "I", etc. as an object.

It does "break the rules" so be careful when using this, if you stray from well-known adjectives, it could confuse a listener/reader.